# Erro acentuação ao salvar arquivo em Python

Tags: python, codificação-de-caracteres, encode

não estou conseguindo salvar um arquivo com acentuação em python, 
venho pedir um help de vocês;

```
import csv


f = open('output.txt', 'w')


data = []

def parse(filename):

    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:

        dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(), delimiters=';')
        csvfile.seek(0)
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect=dialect)

        for line in reader:             

            f.write("%s\n" % line)

parse('Soap.csv')
f.close()
```

sempre tenho  como resultado strings como:

> Observa\xe7\xf5es

e gostaria que a saída fosse como:

> Observações

Comment: O que acontece se você fizer `f.write("%s\n" % unicode(line, "utf-8"))`?

Comment: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found

Comment: cada linha q estou salvando é uma lista

Comment: Então converte para string antes e aplica o unicode: `unicode(str(line), "utf-8")` e veja se isso resolve o problema.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, não deu nenhum erro, mas a saída foi a mesma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Então - o maior problema aí é que você tem em mãos um objeto `list`, retornado pela iteração no "reader" - e e está tentando escrever essa lista direto num arquivo texto de saída, converendo-a em string apenas com o operdor `%` na linha `f.write("%s\n" % line)`.

Essa transformação da lista em string (mesmo que você estivesse usando o método `.format` de strings em vez do `%`), usa a representação interna (`repr`)  de cada elemento da lista - não sua representação com `str`). Se fosse em Python 3 o seu código teria funcionado, por que a representação interna para caractéres acentuados simples exibe os mesmos, em vez da codificação com escape ("\xHH" para as byte-strings em Python 2, \uHHHH para as strins de texto de Python 3).

No entanto, o correto mesmo é codificar gravar cada string da lista separadamente - assegurando que o Python use internamente a representação dada por `str` - adaptando o seu código, ele pode ficar assim - assumindo que você queria que o arquivo de saída possa ser lido exatamente como o seu código tenta: em cada linha lista de strings usando a sintaxe do Python:

```
import csv

def parse(filename):

    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile, open('output.txt', 'w') as f:

        dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(), delimiters=';')
        csvfile.seek(0)
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect=dialect)

        for line in reader:

            f.write("[%s]" % ", ".join("'%s'" % field for field in line)  )

parse('Soap.csv')
```

Note que eue arrumei outro ponto gritante do seu código que é abrir um arquivo pra escrita no corpo do módulo, e fecha-lo no corpo do módulo, sem nenhum tratamento de erro, e com a função assumindo o arquivo aberto como variável global.

Seo arquivo for ser usado em mais de uma função, ou em mais chamadas para a mesma função: (1) crie uma outra funao para encapsular todas as chamadas que vão gravar no arquivo; (2) de preferencia ao comando "with" para abrir (e fechar automaticamente) o arquivo de escrita; (3) passe o arquivo aberto como parâmetro, explicitamente, para todas as funções que vão usa-lo.

Agora, como eu mencionei antes, esse código usa Python 2, e funciona quase que por acaso.  Por que você está tratando dados de texto -tanto do seu arquivo de entrada, quando da saída - sem tentar decodificar os dados lidos ou codificar os escritos para um encoding específico. E esse tipo de coisa que deixa o Python 2 tão difícil - as pessoas assumem qeu está "certo", mas o tal "\xe9" tanto pode ser um "é" se a codificação for "latin1", quanto qualquer oturo caractere se a codificação for Grego, alfabeto Cirílico, Hebreu ou outra língua.

Em Python 2 o módulo csv é bem limitado pra iar com texto de verdade - reuqer a decodificação manual de cada elemento deposi de lido. Em Python 3 ele já decodifica o texto automaticamente.

Então, assumindo que você esteja lendo um arquivo CSV em Latin 1 e queira sua saída em utf-8, por exemplo, pode fazer assim:

```
import csv
INPUT_CODEC = "latin1"
OUTPUT_CODEC = "utf-8"
def parse(filename):

    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile, open('output.txt', 'w') as f:

        dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(), delimiters=';')
        csvfile.seek(0)
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect=dialect)

        for line in reader:
            line = [field.decode(INPUT_CODEC) for field in line]

            f.write("[%s]" % ", ".join("'%s'" % field.encode(OUTPUT_CODEC) for field in line))

parse('Soap.csv')
```

Já em Python 3, você passa as codificações no momento de abrir os arquivos, e o Python faz o decoding e encoding pra você. Se não passar ele tenta usar valores default apropriados a partir do contexto do sistema operacional:

```
with open(filename, 'r', encoding="latin1") as csvfile, open('output.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f:
```

Ainda há uma outra questão - se suas strings contiverem quebras de linha e possivelmente alguns outros caractéres, essas quebras de linha ("\n")  vão entrar direto no seu arquivo de saída, fazendo com que se tornem de leitura difícil - e sintaticamente inválidos como "uma lista de Python por string" - isso é, se no seu CSV tiver algo como `'palavra 1; "batatinha quando nasce\n esparrama pelo chão"; palavra  3`, o "enter" dentro  da segunda coluna sera lido corretamente pelo leitor de CSV (por causa das aspas) - e será gravado no seu arquivo de saída.

Para evitar isso, você pode escapar a quebra de linha e mais alguns caracteres especiais no arquivo de saída: isso é converter caracteres que comprometem a estrutura do arquivo em sequencias substitutas, que não causem problemas para o arquivo e sejam interpretadas  na volta - uma das formas de ler seu arquivo de saída e'fazendo um "eval" em cada linha, por exemplo. Uma forma segura é usar os métodos `urllib.quote` para gravar cada string e `urllib.unquote` - mas isso vai exigir um trtaamento na leitura, e vai gerar um arquivo dificil de ler  e editar a mão. Outra forma é só trocar cada "\" real por duas "\", e, em seguida, todos os "\n" (um único caractere com  codigo decimal 10) por `"\\n"` (dois caractere, a "\" e o "n") - dessa forma quando o Python fizer um "eval", vai ler a sequência "\"  como uma única "\" e vai interpretar  o "\n" no arquivo de texto como um único caractere "new line".